# How to simulate the reverse order of destructor calls in C++?

Tags: c++, destructor, destroy

I want to propagate some information from a base object to derived ones. There is only one problem: I want to do it on object destruction.

The concrete task is to report a time measure:

```
class Counter {
  using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
  using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;
  TimePoint start_ = Clock::now();

 public:
  ~Counter() { /* Propagate |start_| and |Clock::now()| */ }
};
```

I *can't* do it this way because the derived virtual method `Report()` is already gone:

```
class Counter {
  using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
  using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;
  TimePoint start_ = Clock::now();

  virtual void Report(TimePoint, TimePoint) = 0;

 public:
  virtual ~Counter() { Report(start_, Clock::now()); }
};
```

I assume there is some kind of a design pattern for this kind of tasks - can you advise any?

Comment: In the `Counter` destructor, the vmt does not point at any derived class anymore, so derived overrides of virtual methods cannot be called.

Comment: Wanting Report(start_, Clock::now()) to be a polymorphic call is fine.  But why does this have to be a virtual method of the Counter class _also_?  Why not a function object (even templated, maybe!) passed into the constructor, to be called in the destructor (inside a try block, of course)?

Comment: @arayq2: That's a reasonable option if the functor doesn't need to use the Derived object in any way.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I agree.  I'm having trouble visualizing why one would want to subclass a clock counter.  Such functionality might properly belong elsewhere, with the counter being used as a mixin (via CRTP, say) if inheritance is insisted upon.

Answer (score 1):

Having the base class provide functionality before the destructor tree runs is pretty common in reference-counting implementations, but the same approach can easily work for you.

```
class Base
{
    using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
    using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;
    TimePoint start_ = Clock::now();

protected:
    virtual void ~Base();

public:
    void Release() { Report(start_, Clock::now(); delete this; }
};
```

Now users will need to call `o->Release()` instead of `delete o`.  You might want to specialize `std::make_unique` for your class in order to automatically provide the correct deleter.

Comment: Instead of the specialization for `std::make_unique`, couldn't he also overload `operator delete()` for his class?

Comment: @0x499602D2: No.  `operator delete()` is a deallocation function, used only after all destructors have run.

Answer (score 0):

You could deposit your counter in a RIAA container e.g. a `std::unique_ptr`, the container can call the appropriate virtual function on the contained counter when the containers destructor is called. `std::unique_ptr` can take a custom deleter for example. But you could also write your own Wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You should never try to call a virtual function during construction or destruction. When the base class destructor is executed, only the base class type is known !

Your design can be modified as follows:

1. Create a data structure that will contain all the necessary information to do the Report, let's call it ReportInfo.

```
class ReportInfo {
  // all the information needed to be passed
}
```

2. Change the base class Counter, so that it is not abstract anymore, add a protected member info of type ReportInfo, and make Report a non virtual function using the ReportInfo info member.

```
class Counter {
  using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
  using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;
  TimePoint start_ = Clock::now();

  protected:
     // this protected member contains the information needed for the Report
     ReportInfo info;

  // forward the Report to the version using the ReportInfo
  void Report(TimePoint s, TimePoint e) {
    Report(info, s, e);
  } 
  // doing the Report work
  void Report(ReportInfo, TimePoint, TimePoint);

 public:
  // a ctor has to be implemented
  Counter();

  virtual ~Counter() { Report(start_, Clock::now()); }
};
```

3. In the destructor of your derived class, set the ReportInfo of the base class as needed, for example, for a derived class SpecialCounter (using a static function to create the Report):

```
virtual ~SpecialCounter() {
    ReportInfo _info = SpecialCounter::createReportInfo();
    // set the base class member
    info = _info;
}
```

Reference is [Effective C++](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html).

Good luck !